# Scroll arrow in Navigation Tabs of actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabhost, android-actionbar-compat, android-navigation

I have chosen action bar with navigation tabs for fulfilling my app requirement.

If I set three tabs in navigation mode, window width is good enough to show all the tabs. When I add more than 3, say 5, tabs are visible and I can access it by scrolling horizontally. Even though, tabs are visible only on scrolling to right and user may not aware that more tabs are available.

Is it possible to add arrow images in Navigation TabView if more tabs were available? I believe navigation tabs are shown in stack view of actionbar. Is there some way to add custom view in stacked layout of actionbar?

Answer (score 0):

possibly unrelated (and feel free to comment as such so that I delete the answer) but have you considered using swipe views instead of ActionBar tabs?

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

They're really easy to use and you can customize them very easily to do what you want and to include any sort of layout you deem applicable to your app. Have a look at

http://viewpagerindicator.com/

for ideas on what's possible.

Comment: That is not unrelated. Yes, I agree I could use viewpager and tabs togather. But just looking out for a way to modify the views which I use now and possibilities to edit theme of app. Thank you for your valuable suggestion.